# socket.io stops working after 500 concurrent connections

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a javascript browser socket.io client simulator which creates concurrent connections (
`io.connect(host, {'force new connection': true});`) to my socket.io node.js server but when the amount of websocket connections is around 545 it suddenly stops working and the client tries to connect via xhr-polling or any other fallback protocol (without any success of course). 
I tried to tweak my server even I couldn't encounter any hardware problems till now. My `ulimit -n` is set to 40960 and `ulimit -s` is 8192.
sysctl -a | grep file output:

```
fs.file-max = 800000  
fs.file-nr = 7520       0       800000
```

I tried to set the http.globalAgent.maxSockets to 40000 but without any effect. Even if I'm trying to connect from different machines (located in different domains, no proxys between) with like only 100 concurrent connections the socket.io server will stop serving when 545 clients are reached.

I read a lot of blogs and stuff like:
[Realtime Nodejs Stresstest Story](http://weblog.bocoup.com/node-stress-test-analysis/)
[Caustiks Blog with 250k+ connections](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/10/node-js-w250k-concurrent-connections/)

Does anyone has another idea what I could have missed to look at? I am using the latest socket.io and node.js I could get. My server is running on ubuntu.

Comment: My guess is that, this is a browser limit.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat I think his line about serving via different machines and the server still dieing rules that out.

Comment: That said, I'm wondering if this is a network equipment problem - not code/config. Try this in a LAN, going through as few pieces of network hardware as possible. If you can reduce it to just a router, that'd be best. My guess is that this should at least increase the limit.